# Search for a specific item in a Array

Tags: ruby

I want to search through the array:

```
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

to see if `"b"` is in it; if it is, then it should say yes. I understand:

```
letters[0..0] == ["a"]
```

I tried this:

```
if letters[0..5] == ["b"]
  puts "Yes, the letter 'b' in there."
else
  puts "No 'b' in the array."
end
```

Comment: letters.select{|l| l == 'a' }

Comment: `if letters.include?("b")`, please read the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#class-Array-label-Obtaining+Information+about+an+Array)

Comment: @crackedmind this would not work in an `if statement`.  It would always pass as it would return at least an empty array.  `if letters.select{|l| l == 'a' }.count > 0; puts "yes, a is in there"; end` is a better solution I believe. But @stefan's solution should be the accepted answer.

Comment: letters.include? works as well. Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. But not sure why people are voting down? Anyhow...thanks!

Comment: You're expected to show some research effort before posting a question, e.g. reading the documentation, finding out what `array[a..b]` does.

Comment: @Stefan: yes I should have done that. Not sure why it has not come to mind to search first. There is a next time. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if letters.index('b')
    puts "yes"
else
    puts "no"
end
```

Answer (score 4):

There's an in-build method to do that:

```
letters.include? "b"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F

```
if letters.include?("b")
  puts "Yes, the letter 'b' in there."
else
  puts "No 'b' in the array."
end
```